# How to click on element using find_elements_by_class_name() using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to following HTML that is on a website I'm trying to scrape:

```
<div class="test-section-container">
    <div>
        <span class="test-section-title">Section Title</span>
        <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0.05rem;"></div>
    </div>
        <div style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); display: flex; line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 0.07rem;">
            <div style="width: 0.5rem; flex-shrink: 0; background-color: rgb(245, 222, 136);"></div>
            <div style="padding: 0.07rem; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="font-size: 0.18rem; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Newsletter 1</div>
                <div style="font-size: 0.13rem; color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">2021 11 8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); display: flex; line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 0.07rem;">
            <div style="width: 0.5rem; flex-shrink: 0; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
            <div style="padding: 0.07rem; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="font-size: 0.18rem; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Newsletter 2 </div>
                <div style="font-size: 0.13rem; color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">2021 11 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the selenium/python code that I'm using:

```
driver.get("http://www.testwesbite.org/#/newsarticles")

results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('test-section-container')
texts = []
for result in results:
    text = result.text
    texts.append(text)
    print(text)
```

This gives me an output off:

```
Newsletter 1
2021 11 8
Newsletter 2
2021 11 3
```

If I use the following code:

```
first_result = results[0]
first_result.click()
```

It does click into the first article but a `results[1]` give me an out of bounds error.

How would I go about click on the second article?

Comment: Thank you - quickly tested results[1] gives me an index out of range even if I haven't not tried results[0]

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: I'm sorry but its not a public facing website.

Comment: OK, what element are you trying to click on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have used `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('test-section-container')` all the following texts:

- Newsletter 1
- 2021 11 8
- Newsletter 2
- 2021 11 3

Are within the `results[0]` element and `results[1]` desn't exists. Hence you face ***out of bounds error***

---

### Solution

To click on each `results[0]` and `results[1]` you can use:

```
driver.get("http://www.testwesbite.org/#/newsarticles")
results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.test-section-container div[style*='nowrap']")
texts = []
for result in results:
    text = result.text
    texts.append(text)
    print(text)
```

Now you can click the individual items as:

```
first_result = results[0]
first_result.click()
```

and

```
second_result = results[1]
second_result.click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense but how would I go about click on one of the items inside that element?

Comment: @Gee1983 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: its working when I change the line to: 
results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.test-section-container div[style*='nowrap']")

Its says By not defined when using By.CSS_SELECTOR

Not sure if I'm using an outdated Selenium.

Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: Added the import for `By`